# On properties of linear orders

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, economics

I have a simple question. Let $A=\{a,b,c,...\}$ be a set and $>$ a total strict order on $2^A$. Total strict order means that for any two subsets of $A$, say $S$ and $S'$, either $S>S'$ or $S'>S$ but not both.

The order has the following property (sometimes called *substitutability*). For any subsets $S,S'\subset 2^A$, this is any two sets of elements of $A$ for which $S>S'$,

$x \in C(S \cup \{x\}$) implies $x \in C(S' \cup \{x\}$)

where $C(B) \subseteq B$ denotes the unique best subset chosen by $>$ when only $B$ is available (it is unique because $>$ is strict, i.e. no indifferences are allowed).

A paper I am reading claims that it is obvious that, if I have $a>b>c$, it follows that $\{a,b\} > \{a,c\}$, given that $>$ is substitutable.

Can somebody explain me why is this obvious? I just don't see it. Thanks.
The paper is here: [people.hss.caltech.edu/~fede/published/echen-oviedo-TE.pdf](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~fede/published/echen-oviedo-TE.pdf). The question is in Example 6.8.

**Edit**: Or why the following order does not satisfy the substitutability condition:
$\{a\} > \{a,c\} > \{a,b\} > \{a,b,c\} > \{b\} > \{b,c\} > \{c\}$

Comment: I deleted my answer as it seems I misunderstood the definition. On a different note, that article's notation is extremely tedious but the definitions themselves are not too hard to understand. I might come back to this later.